# Error starting bundle in karaf: "via two dependency chains"

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, apache-felix

I am currenty developing a camel route which reads from a netty4/mllp endpoint and store the hl7 message to a amqp queue.

This is my environment:

- apache-maven-3.3.9
- apache-karaf-4.1.1
- apache-camel-2.18.3
- apache-artemis-2.0.0

this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>*****</groupId>
<artifactId>*****</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>*****</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}-bundle</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Activator>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.*****.*****</Bundle-Activator>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-netty4</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-hl7</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I can run the project in eclipse with a "main" class with no problem. But when I am deploying the bundle to the Karaf container I am experiencing some issues.

I am generating the bundle jar, with the previus pom.xml file, with the apache felix plugin, `maven clean package` goal.

The karaf installation is a clean one. I have only setup the following:

- the artemis amqp broker inside the same karaf container

`feature:repo-add artemis
feature:install artemis-amqp`

- the camel components

`feature:repo-add camel
feature:install camel-core camel-netty4 camel-amqp camel-hl7`

I copy the jar bundle into the deploy folder and try to start it with `bundle:start my-bundle` but I get the following error.

```
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
Error starting bundle 110: Unable to resolve demograficos-bundle [110](R 110.0): missing requirement [demograficos-bundle [110](R 110.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.jms)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[demograficos-bundle [110](R 110.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.jms)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
```

I understand from this that the jms implementation is missing from the container.

I tried `feature:install jms`, but now I got the following error

```
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
        Error starting bundle 110: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource demograficos-bundle [demograficos-bundle [110](R 110.0)] because it is exposed to package 'javax.jms' from resources org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_1.1_spec [org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_1.1_spec [120](R 120.0)] and org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec [org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec [75](R 75.0)] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  demograficos-bundle [demograficos-bundle [110](R 110.0)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.jms)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.jms
  org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_1.1_spec [org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_1.1_spec [120](R 120.0)]

Chain 2:
  demograficos-bundle [demograficos-bundle [110](R 110.0)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.amqp)(version>=2.18.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.amqp; uses:=javax.jms
  org.apache.camel.camel-amqp [org.apache.camel.camel-amqp [86](R 86.0)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.jms)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.jms
  org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec [org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec [75](R 75.0)] Unresolved requirements: [[demograficos-bundle [110](R 110.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.amqp)(version>=2.18.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))]
```

But I can't see the two previus geronimo bundles listed, only one

```
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
 ID | State     | Lvl | Version        | Name
----+-----------+-----+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 28 | Active    |  80 | 4.1.1          | Apache Karaf :: OSGi Services :: Event
 52 | Active    |  80 | 19.0.0         | Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java
 53 | Active    |  80 | 4.1.6.Final    | Netty/Buffer
 54 | Active    |  80 | 4.1.6.Final    | Netty/Codec
 55 | Active    |  80 | 4.1.6.Final    | Netty/Codec/HTTP
 56 | Active    |  80 | 4.1.6.Final    | Netty/Common
 57 | Active    |  80 | 4.1.6.Final    | Netty/Handler
 58 | Active    |  80 | 4.1.6.Final    | Netty/Resolver
 59 | Active    |  80 | 4.1.6.Final    | Netty/Transport
 60 | Active    |  80 | 3.0.0          | Expression Language 3.0 API
 61 | Active    |  80 | 1.2.0          | CDI APIs
 62 | Active    |  80 | 1.2            | javax.interceptor API
 63 | Active    |  80 | 1.2            | javax.transaction API
 64 | Active    |  80 | 2.0.0          | ActiveMQ Artemis AMQP Protocol
 65 | Active    |  80 | 2.0.0          | ActiveMQ Artemis Native POM
 66 | Active    |  80 | 2.0.0          | ActiveMQ Artemis Server OSGi
 67 | Active    |  80 | 1.1.1          | Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint
 68 | Active    |  80 | 2.1.0          | Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint
 69 | Active    |  80 | 1.3.2          | Apache Aries Transaction Manager
 70 | Active    |  80 | 1.9.2          | Apache Commons BeanUtils
 71 | Active    |  80 | 3.2.2          | Apache Commons Collections
 72 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.2          | Apache Felix Coordinator Service
 75 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.0.alpha-2  | Apache Geronimo JMS Spec 2.0
 76 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.0.alpha-1  | Apache Geronimo JSon Spec 1.0
 77 | Active    |  80 | 0.9.5          | Johnzon :: Core
 81 | Active    |  80 | 0.20.0         | QpidJMS Client
 82 | Active    |  80 | 0.16.0         | proton-j
 83 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.0.2        | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: javax.inject
 84 | Active    |  80 | 3.3.0.Final    | JBoss Logging 3
 85 | Active    |  80 | 3.6.9.Final    | JGroups
 86 | Active    |  50 | 2.18.3         | camel-amqp
 87 | Active    |  50 | 2.18.3         | camel-catalog
 88 | Active    |  50 | 2.18.3         | camel-commands-core
 89 | Active    |  50 | 2.18.3         | camel-core
 90 | Active    |  50 | 2.18.3         | camel-jms
 91 | Active    |  80 | 2.18.3         | camel-karaf-commands
 92 | Active    |  50 | 1.6.0          | Commons Pool
105 | Active    |  50 | 4.1.7.Final    | Netty/Transport/Native/Epoll
106 | Active    |  50 | 2.18.3         | camel-netty4
107 | Active    |  50 | 2.2            | HAPI - Java HL7 API - OSGI Bundle
108 | Active    |  50 | 2.18.3         | camel-hl7
109 | Active    |  50 | 2.0.14         | Apache MINA Core
110 | Installed |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | **********
111 | Active    |  80 | 2.0.0          | ActiveMQ Artemis HornetQ Protocol
112 | Active    |  80 | 2.0.0          | ActiveMQ Artemis HQClient Protocol
114 | Active    |  80 | 4.1.6.Final    | Netty/Codec/MQTT
115 | Active    |  80 | 2.0.0          | ActiveMQ Artemis MQTT Protocol
116 | Active    |  80 | 2.0.0          | ActiveMQ Artemis OpenWire Protocol
117 | Active    |  80 | 2.0.0          | ActiveMQ Artemis STOMP Protocol
118 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.1          | geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec
119 | Active    |  80 | 1.11.0         | hawtbuf
123 | Active    |  80 | 4.1.1          | Apache Karaf :: JMS :: Core





karaf@root()> bundle:tree-show *****
Bundle **********-bundle [110] is currently INSTALLED
- import javax.jms;version="[1.1,2)": resolved using org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_1.1_spec [122]
- import org.apache.camel;version="[2.18,3)": resolved using org.apache.camel.camel-core [89]
- import org.apache.camel.builder;version="[2.18,3)": resolved using org.apache.camel.camel-core [89]
- import org.apache.camel.component.amqp;version="[2.18,3)": resolved using org.apache.camel.camel-amqp [86]
- import org.apache.camel.component.hl7;version="[2.18,3)": resolved using org.apache.camel.camel-hl7 [108]
- import org.apache.camel.impl;version="[2.18,3)": resolved using org.apache.camel.camel-core [89]
- import org.apache.camel.model;version="[2.18,3)": resolved using org.apache.camel.camel-core [89]
- import org.apache.camel.spi;version="[2.18,3)": resolved using org.apache.camel.camel-core [89]
- import org.osgi.framework;version="[1.8,2)": resolved using org.apache.felix.framework [0]
- import org.slf4j;version="[1.7,2)": resolved using org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
- import org.slf4j;version="[1.7,2)": resolved using org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
- import org.slf4j;version="[1.7,2)": resolved using org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]

Warning: the below tree is a rough approximation of a possible resolution
demograficos-bundle [110]
+- org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_1.1_spec [122]
|  +- javax.transaction-api [63]
|     +- javax.enterprise.cdi-api [61]
|     |  +- javax.el-api [60]
|     |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject [83]
|     |  +- javax.interceptor-api [62]
|     +- javax.interceptor-api [62]
+- org.apache.camel.camel-core [89]
|  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|  |  +- org.apache.karaf.services.eventadmin [3]
|  |     +- org.apache.felix.metatype [2]
|  |     +- org.apache.felix.configadmin [7]
|  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-tx [102]
|     +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|     +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aopalliance [93]
|     +- javax.transaction-api [63]
|     +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop [95]
|     |  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|     |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aopalliance [93]
|     |  +- org.apache.commons.pool [92]
|     |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans [96]
|     |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|     |  |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject [83]
|     |  |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core [99]
|     |  |     +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|     |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core [99]
|     +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans [96]
|     +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core [99]
|     +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context [97]
|        +- org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec [75]
|        |  +- javax.transaction-api [63]
|        +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|        +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject [83]
|        +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-expression [100]
|        |  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|        |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core [99]
|        +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aopalliance [93]
|        +- javax.interceptor-api [62]
|        +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop [95]
|        +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans [96]
|        +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core [99]
+- org.apache.camel.camel-amqp [86]
|  +- org.apache.camel.camel-core [89]
|  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec [75]
|  +- org.apache.qpid.jms.client [81]
|  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec [75]
|  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|  |  +- io.netty.handler [57]
|  |  |  +- io.netty.codec [54]
|  |  |  |  +- io.netty.buffer [53]
|  |  |  |  |  +- io.netty.common [56]
|  |  |  |  |     +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|  |  |  |  +- io.netty.transport [59]
|  |  |  |  |  +- io.netty.resolver [58]
|  |  |  |  |  |  +- io.netty.common [56]
|  |  |  |  |  +- io.netty.buffer [53]
|  |  |  |  |  +- io.netty.common [56]
|  |  |  |  +- io.netty.common [56]
|  |  |  +- io.netty.buffer [53]
|  |  |  +- io.netty.transport [59]
|  |  |  +- io.netty.common [56]
|  |  +- io.netty.codec-http [55]
|  |  |  +- io.netty.codec [54]
|  |  |  +- io.netty.handler [57]
|  |  |  +- io.netty.buffer [53]
|  |  |  +- io.netty.transport [59]
|  |  |  +- io.netty.common [56]
|  |  +- org.apache.qpid.proton-j [82]
|  |  +- io.netty.buffer [53]
|  |  +- io.netty.transport [59]
|  |  +- io.netty.common [56]
|  +- org.apache.camel.camel-jms [90]
|     +- org.apache.camel.camel-core [89]
|     +- org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec [75]
|     +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|     +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms [101]
|     |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec [75]
|     |  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|     |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-tx [102]
|     |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-expression [100]
|     |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aopalliance [93]
|     |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop [95]
|     |  +- io.netty.transport [59]
|     |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans [96]
|     |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core [99]
|     |  +- io.netty.common [56]
|     |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context [97]
|     +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-tx [102]
|     +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans [96]
|     +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core [99]
|     +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context [97]
+- org.apache.camel.camel-hl7 [108]
|  +- org.apache.camel.camel-core [89]
|  +- io.netty.codec [54]
|  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|  +- org.apache.camel.camel-netty4 [106]
|  |  +- org.apache.camel.camel-core [89]
|  |  +- io.netty.codec [54]
|  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|  |  +- io.netty.handler [57]
|  |  +- io.netty.transport [59]
|  |  +- io.netty.buffer [53]
|  |  +- org.apache.commons.pool [92]
|  |  +- io.netty.transport-native-epoll [105]
|  |  |  +- io.netty.buffer [53]
|  |  |  +- io.netty.transport [59]
|  |  |  +- io.netty.common [56]
|  |  +- io.netty.common [56]
|  +- org.apache.mina.core [109]
|  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]
|  +- io.netty.buffer [53]
|  +- ca.uhn.hapi.osgi-base [107]
|  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec [75]
|  +- io.netty.transport [59]
+- org.apache.felix.framework [0]
+- org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [5]

WARNING: multiple bundles are exporting package javax.jms
- org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec [75]
- org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_1.1_spec [122]
```

I am really having some troubles understanding how jar/bundle versions work together under karaf.

Any ideas? maybe I should change the felix plugin in the pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you declared your own bundle exporting the javax.jms package to be in version 1.1, while Artemis depends on a bundle exporting javax.jms in version 2.0, make sure you also depend on a version 2.0 javax.jms version (as that's the version used by artemis) and your issue will be gone.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I do that? I do not understand why I am using jms 1.1 since I have not any references to it in my pom.xml

Comment: must be in your transitive dependencies, best to add a dedicated dependency to a jms 2.0 providing jar in your maven pom.

Comment: I have add the following to the felix maven plugin configuration
`<Import-Package>javax.jms;version="[2.0,3)",*</Import-Package>`
and now it is working.